# Defining sets in intuitionistic logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, paradoxes, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I'm somewhat familiar with the school of intuitionistic logic.  I know that an intuitionistic logician thinks of infinity as constructive as apposed to complete.  Thus a intuitionistic logician cannot justify principles like the law of excluded middle and double negation elimination. I'm wondering how infinite sets are defined from a constructive point of view?

It is my understanding that intuitionism was a response to the paradoxes in the foundations of mathematics.  How does intuitionism address Russel's Paradox for example? Can we even define a set of all sets which do not contain itself in intuitionistic logic.  (This is asked from a non-formal perspective similar to Brouwer's.)

Comment: Why "higher order informal logic"? Russell's paradox was a problem with a formal, first order system; and modern set theory, as a mathematical discipline, is almost entirely concerned with formal, first order theories.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Is intuitionistic logic only applied to formal logic?

Comment: Logic, as an object of mathematical study, *is* formal logic.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I guess I was wondering the question in informal logic because in my text, intuitionism was introduced informal first before building a system for classical and intuitionistic logic.  I have also seen lectures of constructive mathematics operating  in higher order informal logic.  That was kinda the perspective I was asking this question.  Was naive set theory formal?

Comment: I see. You might want to clarify what you mean by "informal higher order logic" in the question, then, because as it is I don't know if the answers I would give in the absence of that parenthetical actually answer your question.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine In my text, it is written in a way that Brouwer's early papers of intuitionism come before the response of Hilbert's formalism.  Do you know any references on the history of the responses to the foundational paradoxes?

Comment: You can see [Set Theory: Constructive and Intuitionistic ZF](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/).

Comment: Finitism and constructivism are orthogonal. Accepting or rejecting the existence of the set of natural numbers neither implies nor requires the law of excluded middle. Constructivism is not really about "infinity".